# How do you use MQTT to control one device among many?

Tags: mqtt

Just getting started with MQTT.

I'm building a desktop application to monitor and control a bunch of network-connected devices. Sometimes this will call for the publish/subscribe style of communication, but in many cases the user will want to select one device and issue commands to it or query it for some data.

Articles about MQTT usually stress the lack of direct connection (or even awareness) between nodes. But if you want to query and control a single device, obviously that's not going to hold. How do you select a single device and address it over MQTT? Publish a message that uses that device's unique identifier as a topic? Or is there some more elegant approach?

An example might be: Some of the devices on the network accumulate audio recordings and place them in files. I want to retrieve a list of the files on a particular device. A few seconds later I might want to tell that device to play back one of those files.

Answer (score 2):

The ONLY addressing in MQTT is the topic names

So you have 2 options

1. Have each device subscribe to a topic that includes a unique identifier for the device.
2. Include the devices unique identifier in the message and only have the device the matches act on it.

The first option is of course far better as it vastly reduces both the bandwidth (as the message is only sent to the right device) and the complexity as you need much less conditional logic on the device.

Comment: That's pretty much what I figured, thanks! I think #1 will work fine.